# How to download a file while sending parameters using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a php script that generates and downloads a file depending on some parameters.

How can I post those parameters and have the file to autodownload on button click.

I thought I could change the btn url every time one of those params changes, but how can I concat those parametters if most of them are arrays?

```
    <a class="btn_clean"
            ng-href="{{ctrl.csv_url}}"
            download="list.csv">
        Export CSV
    </a>
```

Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: Are the parameters arrays, or are they contained in an array? In the latter, you should check [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join)

Comment: I need to send an object which most of its properties are arrays

Comment: I think you should give us an example of expected url. How does it work outside of angularjs?

Comment: doesn't work outside of angular

Comment: Well you've got a PHP backend, I guess you could imagine calling it from a browser. Right now I don't know how it expects its parameters. Does it extracts them from $GET or $POST? Does it run JSON marshalling on the extracted strings? It could do a lot of things we can't infer here

Comment: when the php is done may do that, but right now it doesn't

Comment: If what you need is a way to properly call an http backend from angular, then $http or even better $resource is what you need. That will handle the JSON (de/)serializing for example. You should call those in a service, that could be invoked by the click of a link or button

Comment: but will the ajax call fire the download? I don't think so

Comment: Well using $location could direct you to the php backend to prompt the user for download, but you'd exit your angular app and would have to reload it after coming back to it. Plus even if $location helps with search parameter, I doubt it would serialize a complex object. $http or $resource could probably retrieve the binary data and then open a new tab serving the file (with a data:// url?).

Answer (score -1):

Hey I'm not sure if you've solved this problem or not, however I believe the best way to do this would be using an angular module built just for this, ng-csv

I wrote about it in [this blog post](http://www.danjamrozik.me/2015/11/15/using-ng-csv-to-serve-a-csv-download/) recently.